# Pause scrapy. Can I get a breakdown?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to be able to start/pause/resume a spider and I am attempting to use

```
scrapy crawl some spiders JOBDIR=crawls/some spider-1
```

However, it's mostly just a copy and paste as there isn't much info about whats actually going on here. Anyone have some more info on the specifics?

I get the first part, but don't know whats actually happening with  `JOBDIR=crawls/some spider-1` part.  I see people putting the code like this

```
scrapy crawl some spiders JOBDIR=crawls/some spider
```

.. without the `-1` and don't know what difference that makes. I did notice this. I tend to pound the CTRL+C to quit and that's apparently bad from what I read and what I experienced because if I retype the code

```
scrapy crawl some spiders JOBDIR=crawls/some spider-1
```

.. it goes straight to finished like the spider is done.

How do I "Reset" it after I make that mistake?  If I take out the `-1` it will work again but I don't know if I am losing something there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As explained in the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html), scrapy allows pausing and resuming crawl, but you need a `JOBDIR` setting.

`JOBDIR` value is supposed to be the [path to a directory on your filesystem](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html#job-directory) to persist various objects scrapy needs to resume what it has to do.

Note that for seperate crawls you need to point to a different directory:

> This directory will be for storing all required data to keep the state
>   of a single job (ie. a spider run). It’s important to note that this
>   directory must not be shared by different spiders, or even different
>   jobs/runs of the same spider, as it’s meant to be used for storing the
>   state of a single job.

Copying what in that docs page:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
             ----------           -------------------
                 |                         |       
         name of your spider               |        
                                           |
                               relative path where to save stuff
```

Another example scrapy crawl command using `JOBDIR` could have been:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -s JOBDIR=/home/myuser/crawldata/myspider_run_32
```

Example timeline:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -s JOBDIR=/home/myuser/crawldata/myspider_run_001
# pause using Ctrl-C ...

# ...lets continue where it was left off
scrapy crawl myspider -s JOBDIR=/home/myuser/crawldata/myspider_run_001
# crawl finished properly.
# (and /home/myuser/crawldata/myspider_run_001 should not contain anything now)

# now you want to crawl a 2nd time, from the beginning
scrapy crawl myspider -s JOBDIR=/home/myuser/crawldata/myspider_run_002
```

Comment: Got it.  I was thinking it was a negative 1 not just naming the file as file #1.  Thanks for explaining everything.